Reset a timer for a power up - unity
I need help with reset the timer of the coroutine i made for a powerup called “speed_pepper”.
I tried with invoke and cancel invoke but it also don't work.
The "speed_peper" needs to be a static var because if its not it will change to false every time it instantiate .
Here is the code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class speedpeper : MonoBehaviour
{

    /////// vars ///////

    private static bool is_peper_active;
    
    void Update()
    {
        peper_movement();
    }

    // trigger speed peper 
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        UI_manager uI_Manager;
        uI_Manager = FindObjectOfType<UI_manager>();

        player player;
        player = FindObjectOfType<player>();

        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            if (is_peper_active == false)
            {
                uI_Manager.add_score();
                is_peper_active = true;
                player.player_speed = 9;
                transform.position = new Vector2(0,800);
                StartCoroutine("speed_peper_deactive");
                Destroy(gameObject,80);
                Debug.Log(is_peper_active);
            }
            else if(is_peper_active == true)
            {   
                uI_Manager.add_score();
                player.player_speed = 9;
                transform.position = new Vector2(0,800);
                StopCoroutine("speed_peper_deactive");
                StartCoroutine("speed_peper_deactive");
                Destroy(gameObject,80);
                Debug.Log("it works");
            }
            
        }
        else if (other.tag == "floor")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
    private void peper_movement()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.down * 3.5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    //cancel speed peper buff
    private IEnumerator speed_peper_deactive()
    {
        player player;
        player = FindObjectOfType<player>();
        
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(10);
        
        is_peper_active = false;
        player.player_speed = 6;
    }
}

I tried using invoke and cancel invoke and its still not working

From what i can see, your approach should work, but seems hard to read and follow - youre trying to keep track of coroutines where you could instead use a single variable. Id suggest changing your coroutine like this:
float activeTimer;
private IEnumerator speed_peper_deactive()
{
    player player;
    player = FindObjectOfType<player>();
    do{
         activeTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
         yield return null; //Wait for next frame, then update timer again.
    } while (activeTimer > 0);
    
    is_peper_active = false;
    player.player_speed = 6;
}

And then you can simply reset your timer by setting it to 10 if the player picks up the pepper-powerup again while its still active.

dude u are amazing <3 i was stuck on it for like 4 days and i tried every single option of stopcorutine and cancelinvoke and all of that, i asked in like 3 different forums and no one had any helpful answer, im new to unity (and coding in general) and u actually made me lern how IEnumerator work and made me a batter programmer ( i also didn't know what a do while loop is doing i only knew about a while loop)

When you use the StopCoroutine method, you need to give it an instance of a coroutine, not the name of the coroutine itself.
First you need a variable to store the coroutine for your timer.
private Coroutine speed_peper_coroutine;

Then when you run StartCoroutine, set this variable.
speed_peper_coroutine = StartCoroutine("speed_peper_deactive");

When you go to stop it, you then pass the variable instead.
StopCoroutine(speed_peper_coroutine);


i tried it.
its still don't stop
i really don't know what is wrong with it lol.

Maybe try replacing StopCoroutine("speed_peper_deactive"); with StopAllCoroutines();
It's not ideal since, as the name implies, it will stop any other coroutine you have on that script but it might work in the very least.
